# Find the Laplace transform:$f(t) = \int_0^t {{e^{it}}\frac{{dt}}{{\sqrt {2\pi t} }}}$

Tags: laplace-transform

Find the Laplace transform of the function:
$$\begin{array}{l}
 f(t) = \int_0^t {{e^{it}}\frac{{dt}}{{\sqrt {2\pi t} }}}  \\ 
 {\rm{Us}}e:\Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right) = \sqrt \pi   \\ 
 \end{array}$$

Comment: I have done:$$\begin{array}{l}
 g(t) = \frac{{{e^{it}}{t^{ - 1/2}}}}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }} \\ 
 L\left[ {g(t)} \right] = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int_0^\infty  {{e^{it}}{t^{ - 1/2}}} dt \\ 
  = \frac{1}{{i\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int_0^\infty  {{e^{ - {i^2}t}}{{({i^2}t)}^{\frac{1}{2} - 1}}} d({i^2}t) = \frac{1}{{i\sqrt {2\pi } }}\Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right) = \frac{{ - i}}{{\sqrt 2 }} \\ 
  =  > L\left[ {\int_0^t {{e^{it}}\frac{{dt}}{{\sqrt {2\pi t} }}} } \right] =  - \frac{i}{{s\sqrt 2 }} \\ 
 \end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{L}_{t\to s}\left\{\int_0^te^{it}\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\right\}=\dfrac{\mathcal{L}_{t\to s}\left\{\dfrac{e^{it}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\right\}}{s}=\dfrac{\mathcal{L}_{t\to s-i}\left\{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\right\}}{s}=\dfrac{1}{s\sqrt{2(s-i)}}$